# Fetching documents sorted by date dynamically. To be used for lazy loading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that you can sort files after you have fetched it using the array of paths from the documents.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    _filePaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

    //do sorting after all file contents are fetched
```

What I want to know: Is it possible to fetch file paths already sorted (e.g. date, or whatever attribute)? Because I don't want to load all the files at once then perform a sort on the long list just to get a definite number of files that I will use for lazy loading.

Comment: Why not save some value to `NSUserDefaults` with the number of files (or even the sorted list of file paths) every time a file is changed?

Comment: Yes there are definitely ways to track this on the moment every file is saved. We can use preference, plist, core-data, etc. I'm just straight forward to know if it is possible to fetch these files sorted by an attribute as date as it is - like viewing files in your computer ordered by date already.